# Alter table failing when i execute a function that modifys the table

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, ddl

I have written a generic function to change ids of students with wrong ids. Since the students table is referenced by other tables i had to drop the foreign keys and disable the triggers temporarily. This is my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_student_id(varchar, varchar) RETURNS varchar AS $$
DECLARE 
old_id ALIAS FOR  $1;
new_id ALIAS FOR  $2;
msg varchar(120);

BEGIN

    --disable triggers
   ALTER TABLE students
   DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;

    ALTER TABLE studentdegrees
    DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;


    ALTER TABLE studentdegrees DROP CONSTRAINT studentdegrees_studentid_fkey;
    UPDATE students 
    SET studentid=new_id
    WHERE studentid=old_id;

    ALTER TABLE studentdegrees
    ADD CONSTRAINT studentdegrees_studentid_fkey
    FOREIGN KEY (studentid)
    REFERENCES students(studentid);

    UPDATE studentdegrees 
    SET studentid=new_id
    WHERE studentid=old_id;

    UPDATE entitys 
    SET user_name=new_id
    WHERE user_name=old_id;

    --enable triggers
    ALTER TABLE students
    ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;

    ALTER TABLE studentdegrees
    ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;

    msg:=old_id|| ' Changed to '||new_id;

RETURN msg;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When i call the function like this

```
SELECT  update_student_id(
studentid, a.stdid)
FROM
(SELECT studentid,  REPLACE(studentid, ' ', '') AS stdid
FROM students
WHERE studentid NOT IN (SELECT REPLACE(studentid, ' ', ''))) AS a
```

I get this error

> ERROR:  cannot ALTER TABLE "students" because it is being used by active queries in this session
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER TABLE studentdegrees DROP CONSTRAINT studentdegrees_studentid_fkey"
>   PL/pgSQL function update_student_id(character varying,character varying) line 17 at SQL statement

Comment: you're trying to modify the design of the "students" table at the same time you're running a SELECT query against that (because the call to the function is within the query which selects from students). That's not allowed. What are you trying to achieve though? Calling the function in this context doesn't entirely make sense to me. If you want to update the student, first run the update function, and then when it's finished, separately run the SELECT query to get the new data.

Comment: And anyway why are you trying to modify ID fields? IDs should be unique to a particular item and persist throughout the life of that item. If you change the ID, it's no longer possible to reliably identify that item (e.g. if you had stored that value elsewhere as a reference to it). If you find yourself having to drop a key in order to change a value, then you probably need to think again about what you're doing.

Comment: You can probably avoid this ugly hack by declaring that foreign key as `deferrable` so that it is checked at the end of your transaction, not for each statement. Or use chained CTEs to do everything in one statement. But I agree with ADyson: why are you changing the primary key of a student to begin with? What makes an ID a "wrong ID"?

Comment: I need to transfer student IDs to another system which has some strict rules on the characters in the ID column, that is why am changing the IDs to comply. As i indicated above the references are well taken care of. Its easier to run it as a single script but wanted it to be a generic function, that is why i needed alternatives

Comment: if you're just transferring the data to another system, why change the IDs in the source system tables? Simply make the necessary modification using string manipulation in the SELECT which exports the data. You never need to change the original data at all.